# Getting an error while writing a custom velocity macro

Tags: macros, velocity, xwiki

When creating my own macro, and trying to add it so that anyone can use it, I get the following error:

```
Error number 4001 in 4: Error while parsing velocity page /templates/docdoesnotexist.vm
```

Wrapped Exception: Cannot start the Velocity engine

I do not change that file, but I do change `xwiki/templates/macros.txt` and `/macros.vm` by adding `recentChanges=velocity:recentChanges:` and `#macro(recentChanges)` respectively (yes, I do add working content after `#macro(recentChanges)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a syntax error in macros.vm. You should revert to the original macros.vm and first try to write your custom macro in a wiki page. Once it works, you can move it to macros.vm and restart the server.

macros.txt shouldn't be edited, it's a legacy file used by the older WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: still does not work. removed addition from macros.txt and .vm, restarted server >> works
create macro in wikipage >> works
copy macro
add macro to macros.vm(
#macro (recent_changes)
  code inserted here
does not work anymore >> this time on view.vm